# Unity3D FindGameObjectsWithTag not recognizing any tags

Tags: unity, loading

I'm at a loss here because I'm not sure what's going on. I understand that tags need to exist first, and that you actually have to assign the tags after creating them, but `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` is not finding ANY tags, including the default tags.

If I try to find MainCamera, which is a built-in tag, I get the following error:

> UnityEngine.UnityException: Tag: MainCamera is not defined. at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string) at UnityEngine.GameObject.FindWithTag (System.String tag) [0x00002]

What do  I do about this? The exact line of code throwing this exception is:

```
mountingObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(attachesTo);
```

I'm trying to load tags from a file and it's not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked around for a long time for the solution to this and wound up solving it right before I clicked post, so here's the answer for anyone else having the same problem:

In loading from a file, I was splitting the text by the newline `\n` character -

```
string[] lines = fileData.Split('\n');
```

The problem is that, on Windows systems, new lines are defined by the [carriage return/line feed sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552782/5171120).

So, while splitting on `\n` was/is splitting each line at approximately the correct location, **`<string>.Split('\n')` leaves a carriage return on the end of each resulting string. That carriage return does not display in debug messages.**

Instead of trying to find the tag `MainCamera`, I was actually trying to find the tag `MainCamera\r` which does not actually exist.

I found this when putting in `"MainCamera"` worked but the data loaded from file did not. I used the following code to debug:

```
string output = "Hex string:";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lineFromFile);
foreach(byte currentByte in bytes)
{
    output += " " + System.Convert.ToString(currentByte, 16);
}
Debug.LogFormat("lineFromFile string is {0}; converts to {1}.", lineFromFile, output);
```

For a line from file that read `MainCamera`, this produced:

```
lineFromFile string is MainCamera; converts to Hex string: 4d 61 69 6e 43 61 6d 65 72 61 d.
```

**Note the `d` at the end of that line!**

Going to an [ASCII lookup table](https://www.ascii-code.com) gives `0D` to be the carriage return operator.

---

So, ultimately, I think a good way to split a file into lines is to replace all the Windows-style line endings, `\r\n`, with the Unix-style (and maybe [Mac-style?](https://superuser.com/a/439443/505681)) `\n` line endings, then to split the file on the `\n`. In this way, if you're on a Unix system, the Replace command just returns the original string (because it didn't find any `\r\n` sequences), and then for both systems you're breaking the lines correctly.

```
string fileData = File.ReadAllText(filename);
string[] lines = fileData.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n');
```